# retrieve custom post types on the bases on mata field values

Tags: wordpress

How to query the custom post types and filter the posts on the bases of meta key value?

let say i have 4 types of products and i am wanted to get the product 2 posts

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: how would like to filter  2 posts ? do you mean by using meta key and meta value comparison ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query by meta key inorder to show the post on meta value basis

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key'       => 'meta_key_name',
  'posts_per_page' => 20
 );

query_posts( $args ); 

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <article>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  </article>
  <?php 
  endwhile; 
endif;
?>
```